# Coproducts in $\mathsf{Grp}$

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

The limits and colimits in the category of abelian groups are as nice as can be, since products and equalizers are the same as in the category of sets.

In the category of groups, however, the coproduct is <s>an unpleasant</s> a less manageable creature. One can show that that's just the way things are, but why is this *really*? Why does the lack of commutative "spoil" things, and what exactly does it spoil?

Comment: Have you heard of the free product of groups? And the free abelian product of abelian groups? These are exactly the coproducts in the corresponding categories.

Comment: @Zardo I know this. What I'm asking is "why" does the absence of commutativity in the category of groups make the coproduct such an unpleasant creature.

Comment: *unpleasant* is just an unfortunate opinion

Comment: You cannot use modul theory! Groups are nothing like vector spaces. There is a huge difference between abelian groups and groups in general. In fact abelian groups are in some way closer to vector spaces than to general groups. - For example the coproduct can be constructed in a very similar fashion. And It's pretty obvious why vector spaces (or modules) are easier to handle than groups, I guess!

Comment: BTW: Modules are like vector spaces with a ring instead of a field. And every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. This explains why the coproduct in both categories is the direct sum: The structural difference is rather small.

Comment: @Zardo I don't understand how this directly explains *how* lack of commutativity makes coproducts less manageable.

Comment: Well, what exactly do you mean by less manageable? Are there some theorems you'd like to generalize?

Comment: @Zardo I mean that the underlying set of the coproduct of groups is not the coproduct of the underlying sets.

Comment: It isn't in abelian groups, either! The coproduct of sets is their disjoint union!

Comment: @Exterior The coproduct in the category of abelian groups also fails to match the coproduct of sets (which is just disjoint union).

Comment: I guess one person's "unpleasant" is another's "fascinating".  I think it is far to say that it is abelian groups (or more generally modules over a ring) that are exceptional in admitting such simple coproducts. Free objects very often don't exist or have a very complicated structure in most of the categories studied in universal algebra, while the usual product construction works for a wide range of categories (specifically any category comprising structures and homomorphisms in the sense of model theory that can be axiomatised by Horn clauses).

Comment: Suppose $G:D\to C$ is a forgetful functor. If $G$ has a left adjoint $F:C\to D$ then $Fc$ is a free object for every $c\in C$. A general existence theorem says that If $c$ is a variety, then such a $F$ exists. As far as when the coproduct and product coincide, this will hold in a category $C$ whenever the hom sets are composable abelian groups such that $\circ_{a,b,c} : Hom_C(a,b) \times Hom_C(b,c) \to Hom_C(a,c)$ is bilinear.

Answer (score 6):

At least in algebraic contexts, I like to think of the coproduct of $(A,\cdot)$ and $(B,*)$ as being the structure which $A\cup B$ generates* (applying the original multiplication between pairs of adjacent elements of $A$ or of $B$). That is, every element of the coproduct must be writable as a product of $A$'s and $B$'s - like (assuming associativity):
$$a_1b_1a_2b_2\ldots a_nb_n.$$
This is, of course, basically what a free product looks like in the category of groups - and we can't proceed further because the group laws alone do not allow us to move around elements, beyond removing identity elements from the product.

When we're in the category of abelian groups, however, we obviously have that
$$a_1b_1a_2b_2\ldots a_nb_n=a_1a_2\ldots a_n b_1b_2\ldots b_n$$
which means that every element may be written as a product of an element of $A$ and an element of $B$ - which is basically what happens in a direct product - meaning those two structures will coincide. So, we can regard that abelian groups are special in that their additional structure lets us simplify the usually complex form of the coproduct.

(*Of course, $(A,\cdot)$ is not actually the signature of a group - but it's still a working illustration)

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, if the sets $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, then the product and coproduct are the same. This means that the object $A\times B\in AGrp$  is a $\textit coproduct$. and we have the canonical insertions $$i_{1}:A\to A\times B;a\mapsto (a,1)$$ and $$i_{2}:B\to A\times B;b\mapsto (1,b)$$ that satisfy the UMP of the coproduct.

We will show by counterexample that the same kind of construction does not work in $Grp$:

Take $A=\left \{ 1,a \right \};a^{2}=1$ and $B=\left \{ 1,b \right \};b^{2}=1$ i.e: $A$ and $B$ are copies of the two-element group. If $A\times B$ is a coproduct, and $i_{1}$ and $i_{2}$ are as above, then define $C$ to be the free group on two generators. i.e. $C$ has elements of the form aaabbaabbbbbb, identity $e=$ the empty word and the multiplication is cancatenation. Note that $C$ is not abelian. i.e. $ab\neq ba$.

Now, let $f:A\to C$ be given by $a\mapsto a$ i.e the word $a$ of length $1$ in $C$ and

$g:B\to C$ be given by $b\mapsto b$.

If $A\times B$ is to satify the UMP of the coproduct, we should be able to find a group homomorphism $h:A\times B\to C$ such that $$h\circ i_{1}=f$$ and $$h\circ i_{2}=g$$

But we may observe that in $A\times B$, we must have $(a,1)(1,b)=(a,b)=(1,b)(a,1)$ so that if such an $h$ existed, we would require

$ab=f(a)g(b)=((h\circ i_{1})(a))((h\circ i_{2})(b))=h(a,1)h(1,b)=h(a,b)=h(1,b)h(a,1)=((h\circ i_{2})(b))((h\circ i_{1})(a))=g(b)f(a)=ba$.

The foregoing implies that if such an $h$ exists, then $ab=ba$. But $C$ is not abelian, so no such $h$ exists $\Rightarrow A\times B$ is not a coproduct.